# seem ages ago meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Harry looked down at his empty gold plate. He had only just realised how hungry he was. **The pumpkin pasties seemed ages ago**.
>
> From Harry Potter

What does *The pumpkin pasties seemed ages ago* mean?

I think it means *It seems like he's eaten the pumpkin pasties ages ago.*

Comment: You're correct. But note that the exaggerated metaphoric ***ages ago*** is an informal usage, *and* I'd say equating *the pumpkin pasties* with ***eating** the pumpkin pasties* is also an informal usage.

Comment: It's somewhat like "We'll always have Paris" as a shorthand for "We'll always have *the memories of our time in* Paris."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it's a shortened way of saying **It seemed as though it was ages ago that he had eaten the pumpkin pasties.**

Answer (score 0):

His most recent meal was when he ate pumpkin pasties. But he feels as hungry now, as if that meal was very long ago. Ages ago. It wasn't very long ago, but it seems that way.